# Cache folder on device powered off

Tags: iphone, iphone-4

Does Cache folder gets cleared when device is powered off? If yes, which folder gets retained -- Documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure when the Cache directory is cleared, but Documents is always retained (and backed up when syncing) until the app is deleted.